# Does PyUserInput switch order of events?

Tags: python-2.7, keyboard, clipboard

i want to write a code, wich copys a text from a window and write it in a form. But this code write the text somehow in the window before clicking in the form. It sometimes also doesnt print the text from clipboard, also you can do that manually. How is that possible and how can i fix that?
Thanks

```
from pymouse import PyMouse
from pykeyboard import PyKeyboard
import clipboard

m = PyMouse()
k = PyKeyboard()

x_dim, y_dim = m.screen_size()

## click in File
m.click(x_dim*3/4, y_dim/2, 1)

## Ctrl a
k.press_key(k.control_key)
k.tap_key('a')
k.release_key(k.control_key)

## Ctrl c
k.press_key(k.control_key)
k.tap_key('c')
k.release_key(k.control_key)

## put it in clipboard
text = clipboard.paste()

## click in form
m.click(x_dim/4, y_dim/2, 1)

## write clipboard and text into form and tab through elements
k.type_string(text)
k.tap_key(k.tab_key)
k.type_string('hello')
k.tap_key(k.tab_key)
k.type_string('test')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check the X/Y positions which you are using for PyMouse. Get the values by printing them out for example and check the position on your screen:

```
## click in form
x_click = x_dim/4
y_click = y_dim/2
m.click(x_click, y_click, 1)
print x_click
print y_click
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,you should check the position of the file in the screen,you should confirm the position parameter is right.The 'print' function may be helpful for you to check the string.